# How do I Paint on has an Image that is used as Texture?

Tags: texturing, uv-image-editor

(I don't have any access to external programs, nor the patience or time to learn them. I want my Blender problems to stay in Blender.)

I have a Picture inside my UV Editor, and I wanted to know a way to apply a material, color, or paint to affect this image, or my mesh.

'This picture wraps around my barrel. I have cracks in the wood itself, and separating the individual planks. I want to apply 'black' to those cracks.'

I wish I could provide visuals, but apparently the 'Blender Forums' doesn't allow 2 images.

Comment: Yes, images would help us understand what you need. You can upload them to any image hosting site and then [edit] your question to add the link. Also, stricltly speaking, this is not a forum, but a question and answer site please take a minute to read the [help] section to familiarize yourself with the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To paint on a mesh in Texture Paint Mode you need a UV unwrapped mesh.

Then, there are a couple of options:

- Paint on a texture using the UV editor.

  Enable Paint Mode and press T to bring up tools for painting

  The image below shows where you toggle paint mode on

  [image]

  Choose the tool you want to use, and paint directly on the image.

  [image]

(Please see [this link](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/painting/texture_paint/introduction.html?highlight=paint) for more info)

- Paint using the 3D viewport.

  Enable paint mode, select your tool and paint directly over the mesh.

  [image]

**IMPORTANT:** After you've painted on the texture **you need to save the image** on the UV/Image Editor. Use Save Image on the menu or <kbd>Alt</kbd>S to overwrite the original image with the changes or use <kbd>F3</kbd> to save as a different file)

[image]

**If you don't save the image and close blender, all of your painted texures will disappear forever**

You might also find this pages from the blender manual useful:

[Texture Painting](https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/painting/index.html)

[UV Unwrapping a Mesh](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/uv_image/uv_editing/unwrapping.html)

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's also possible to texture paint directly on the textured mesh on the 3d view , since OP mentioned this.

Comment: Added picture for find texture paint mode on 3D view now.

Comment: So cegaton... you edited pretty much my whole answer instead of making your own... nice one

Comment: I saw your previous comment Ari. Yeah, that was a dick move by his part. But unfortunately I can't do anything about that. Thanks for the help.